# Changing Default Version of Elixir After Upgrade?

Tags: macos, elixir, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade Elixir on Mac OSX.  Homebrew shows that I've upgraded successfully.  But when I run elixir --version, I get the old version??

Is there an extra step I need to do to set the upgraded version to the default?

Here's the relevant terminal messages...

```
22:~ 22$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.4
22:~ 22$ brew update

Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
guile@2.0
==> Updated Formulae
bazel@0.2    folly        harfbuzz     libgosu      scalaenv     terragrunt
22:~ 22$ 
22:~ 22$ brew upgrade elixir
Error: elixir 1.4.2 already installed
22:~ 22$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.3.4
22:~ 22$
```

Comment: Is that the only way you installed elixir? What does `which elixir` say?

Comment: I tried an install using macports as well.  Here's what I'm getting from which elixir: /opt/local/bin/elixir

Comment: That sounds like it is installed from macports. Either uninstall it from macports. Or, if you plan on use homebrew, just uninstall macports.

Comment: Maybe try removing both homebrew and macports and then install only one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the version is already installed (but not activated)

```
$ brew info elixir
```

If you get multiple versions then:

```
$ brew switch elixir 1.4.2
```

If this not working, check the other ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/860614)

Answer (score 1):

I don't bother with brew for elixir since the build form source is so dead simple. I do use brew for erlang.

```
get clone https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir.git
cd elixir
git checkout v1.4.2
make clean && make && sudo make install
```

The make clean is not necessary on the first build, but is needed when you change versions.

When your ready to update to a later version

```
git fetch origin
git checkout <new-tag>
make clean && make && sudo make install
```

Has not failed me yet.

Comment: I have a Gentoo background so I always build from source. `brew install -s elixir` :- )